# customize single Magento 2 category page to display ALL new products from root category

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

I use Magento 2.4.1 and I need to set up a single menu link [eg. men] which is linked to a category that will show ALL the new products in the entire website and also any product with an attribute 'new' set to yes.

I need the resultant page to have side bar filters like a category page.

I will prefer if the resultant page is a category page so it means that the adjustment needs to affect only the single menu link [eg men]

Comment: aaaand your question is?

Comment: Can you please add code you have tried yet?

Comment: @diana-botean, how do i get this done?